# Cant get array from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have asp.net application where need to implement autocomplete, I try to load list of names from server side and then deserealize it in js code, but have an 500 error, can anybody help me?

```
Unknown web method GetListofCompanies.
Parameter name: methodName
```

**Code:**

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetListofCompanies(string name) {
        var companies = _companyRepo.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        // Create a JSON object to create the response in the format needed.
        JavaScriptSerializer oJss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        // Create the JSON response.
        String strResponse = oJss.Serialize(companies);

        return strResponse;

    }
```

**JS:**

```
var name = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: "Company.aspx/GetListofCompanies",
            type: "post",
            data: { name: name },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                // Get the data.
                var responseArray = JSON.parse(data.d);
                $("#txtName").autocomplete({
                    source: responseArray
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you show the response of ajax call?

Comment: make sure that the url is right,,

Comment: yes, url right, I have this code inside Company.aspx.cs

Comment: I suppose you need the static keyword

Comment: Add static keyword and replace _companyRepo to Repository<Company>() and have next error: ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException"
Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: name."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Namespaces.
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;   

[WebMethod]
public static string GetListofCompanies(string name)
{
    List<string> companies = new List<string>();
    companies.Add("Company1");
    companies.Add("Company2");
    companies.Add("Company3");
    companies.Add("Company4");
    companies.Add("Company5");

    // Create a JSON object to create the response in the format needed.
    JavaScriptSerializer oJss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    // Create the JSON response.
    String strResponse = oJss.Serialize(companies);

    return strResponse;
}

   // JS
   function request() {
        var name = "";
        var data = { name: name };
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/GetListofCompanies",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).success(function (data) {
            // do your stuff here
        })
        .fail(function (e) {
            alert("Error");
        });
    }
```